# Why I'm able to access WebSocket native browser object in node/jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have browser code which uses the native implementation of WebSocket aka
`var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080')`

While this code runs perfectly in my browser, I expect it to fail miserably when running the code with jest.

But surprisingly, I don't have error and it appears to works perfectly well.
I'm also surprised to not have any better output in the console, I cannot inspect this object to see what I have access to.

```
test('should fail because I cannot see any WebSocket API in node.js doc', async () => {
    await new Promise( resolve => {
      const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080')

      socket.onopen = function( event ){
        console.log( event )
        console.log( socket )
        console.log( socket.onopen )

        resolve()
      }
    })
})
```

It produces the following output:

```
console.log tests/socket/socket.test.js:5
  Event { isTrusted: [Getter] }
console.log tests/socket/socket.test.js:6
  WebSocket {}
console.log tests/socket/socket.test.js:7
  [Function]
```

Why is this working in jest ? Why I don't have to use a library like ws or socket.io when I test my browser code in jest ?
Is this because of jest ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jest by default runs your test in [JSDOM](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) which implements `WebSocket`. See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string